# How can we split string using windows bat

Tags: batch-file

How can we split string using windows bat script?

for below .bat code snippet

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set j=0

for /f "delims=""" %%i in (config.ini) do (
set /a j+=1
set con!j!=%%i
call set a=%%con!j!%%
echo !a!
(echo !a!|findstr "^#">nul 2>nul && (
    rem mkdir !a!
) || (
    echo +) 
    rem for /f "tokens=2" %%k in(config.ini) do echo %%k
)
)
pause
```

below config file
[image: test config file]

**Q**

2. What's wrong when I del **rem** at the begin of *rem for /f "tokens=2" %%k in(config.ini) do echo %%k*
3. How can I get the */path/to/case* and *value* as a pair?
   `for /f xxxx in (testconfig.ini) do (set a=/path/to/case1 set b=vaule1)`

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43407067.txt"

set j=0

for /f "delims=""" %%i in (%filename1%) do (
set /a j+=1
set con!j!=%%i
call set a=%%con!j!%%
echo !a! SHOULD BE EQUAL TO %%i
(echo !a!|findstr "^#">nul 2>nul && (
    echo mkdir !a!
) || (
    echo +)
    for /f "tokens=2" %%k IN ("%%i") do echo "%%k"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%j IN ("%%i") do echo "%%j" and "%%k"
)
)
ECHO ----------------------------
SET con

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q43407067.txt` containing your data for my testing.

(These are setting that suit my system)

SO - to address your problems:

1. because the `)` on that line closes the `(` on the previous. The `)` on *that* line closes the `(` on the one prior. (I changed the `rem` to an `echo` so that the code would produce something visible) The first `(` on the `(echo !a!` line is closed by the `)` on the line following the (now) two `for /f` commands. and the `(` on the `for..%%i..do(` is closed by the final `)` before the `echo -----`

You can't delete that `)` because it's participating in a parenthesis-pair.

2. You need a space between the `in` and the `(`.
3. I've shown a way. See `for /?|more` from the prompt for documentation (or many articles here on SO)

In your code, `!a!` is the same as `%%i` - so I've no idea why you are conducting all the gymnastics - doubtless to present a *minimal example showing the problem*.

Note that since the default delimiters include <kbd>Space</kbd> then if any line contains a space in the `/path/to/case` or `value` then you'll have to re-engineer the approach.

Comment: Yes，than you very much;I have resolved this issue with you strong help.

Answer (score 0):

I' not sure if I understand what exactly it is you need, so what follows may not suit your needs:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "n=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (testConfig.ini) Do (Set "_=%%A"
    If "!_:~,1!"=="#" (Set/A "n+=1", "i=0"
        Echo=MD %%A
        Set "con[!n!]!i!=%%A") Else (For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ('Echo=%%A'
        ) Do (Set/A "i+=1"
            Set "con[!n!]!i!=%%B"&&Set/A "i+=1"&&Set "con[!n!]!i!=%%C")))
Set con[
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF
```

*remove `Echo=` on line 6 if you are happy with the output and really want to create those directories*

Comment: set b=
for /f "delims=""" %%i in (config.ini) do (
 set /a j+=1
 set con!j!=%%i
 call set a=%%con!j!%%
 rem echo !a!
 echo !a!|findstr "^#">nul 2>nul && (
  rem echo =======mkdir=====
  set b=!a!
  mkdir "%LogDir%\!a!"
 ) || (
  echo !b!
  for /F "eol=# tokens=1,2" %%x in ("%%i") do (
   echo key  %%x  value%%y
  )
 )
)